# Using 'useReducer' inside 'createContext'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to write a context provider for an app I am working on, I've created the following file:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import { initialState, playerUiReducer } from './reducers/player-ui'

const PlayerStateContext = createContext(useReducer(playerUiReducer, initialState))

export default PlayerStateContext
```

This worked fine until I replaced the hardcoded data with the `useReducer` hook but now it gives me the following error:

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`

Is there no way to use `useReducer` without creating a react component to wrap it in? I'd rather just pass it down via the context as I really don't want to use JSX if I can help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value passed to createContext is not used when you do not have any provider in the hierarchy. Its not actually required to pass a default value if you have a proper setup

Also as the error suggests, hooks are meant to be used within `functional components` and not outside of it

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import { initialState, playerUiReducer } from './reducers/player-ui'

const PlayerStateContext = createContext();

export default PlayerStateContext
```

You must pass on the value to `PlayerContext` provider instead

```
const App = () => {
   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(playerUiReducer, initialState);
   return (
      <PlayerStateContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
          {/* code here */}
      </PlayerStateContext.Provider>
   )
}
```

Comment: One nitpick: this will rerender the whole app every time `<App/>` renders because a new value is passed to the `Provider` every render. You could memoize it with `useMemo(() => [state, dispatch], [state])` to ensure the value only changes when the `state` does (`dispatch` is guaranteed constant).